# Can I order the enum values in intellisense?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2005, intellisense

I have an eum type with 5 members.  Is it possible to tell intellisense to order them the way I want?

```
public enum numbers
{
    zero,
    one,
    two,
    three,
    four
}
```

Intelisense shows (in alpha):

```
four
one
three
two
zero
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No you cant. But the Visual Studio team has considered the suggestion even though not exactly the way you would want it. But hey, its a start.

You can vote on the link @sepster provided:

https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/Intellisense-display-enums-by-numeric-or/871057?space=8&entry=suggestion

---

Edit: Microsoft connect has been retired. Leaving this here for future reference.

See the Microsoft connect response here
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=419602

I have added your requirement as a comment on the site.

Comment: Too bad they aren't thinking of doing something like letting you put an attribute on your declaration to indicate the sort order (maybe alphabetical, value (like the underlying numerical value associated with the enumeration members), plus a few others maybe).

Comment: Great, thanks!  I would like to see it as an attribute as well.

Comment: Would you mind suggesting the attribute idea Bobby (since you are already a member of that community)? Unless of course you think the idea is crap =)

Comment: No, I think the idea is perfectly reasonable. I'll put in the idea as a comment.

Comment: Jason, I have added your suggestion as a comment.

Comment: Anything ever come of this suggestion? The link is no good anymore (unsurprising as it over 6 years ago).

Comment: It's kinda ridiculous that you can't set it to list members by declaration order, I'd really love this while developing in c++

Comment: Any change in almost 2019? You always declare your members in some logical order, what's the point of sorting it alphabetically right after dot, where you did't type anything yet. I don't even see a need for some redundant attributes, just don't sort it if you don't have input...

Comment: Couldn't find the original request you've linked, on the new community site, @bobbyalex.  But found this one that we should all vote for! [https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/Intellisense-display-enums-by-numeric-or/871057?space=8&entry=suggestion]

Comment: @Sepster agree and done but i fear the truth is that even though most would kill for such a feature it'll never get enough votes per design.

Answer (score 9):

I think the only way to do that would be to do something like

```
public enum numbers
{
    num_00,
    num_01,
    num_02,
    num_03,
    num_04
}
```

Answer (score 8):

No you can't as far as I know. Intellisense orders them alphabetically.

Answer (score 3):

well if you use this kind of declaration for enum intellisense will sort by the first character

by diffrewnt kind of declartion i mean you can start the enum like 
_0 
_1 
_2 like that where _ will have the same previlage and then 
0 
1 
2 
etc will be used to reorder it.

Comment: Are you suggesting a different kind of declaration?  Actually in my code I assign them all in values but I see the same thing in intellisense.

Comment: by diffrewnt kind of declartion i mean you can start the enum like 
_0
_1
_2
like that where _ will have the same previlage and then 0 1 2 etc will be used to reorder it.

Comment: This is a good approach. You can do something like enum MyPermissionLevel { _00_basic, _01_standard, _02_power_User, _03_advanced }, and it will show up sorted in Intellisense, and also give an indication of the importance of the sort order within the enum (useful if you do something like if user.PermissionLevel >= PermissionLevel._02_power_user)